# How do i replicate files between two different file structures?

Tags: filesystems, replication, file-replication-services

I've got a directory which contains hundreds of thousands of files. A file typically looks like this : `CED375_description_01.jpg`. I need to move this file to another directory, but the file needs to be moved into the structure `/ced/ced375/ced375_description_01.jpg`.

What options do I have to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not aware of an application that  will do this for you. Your most likely solution is to write a script yourself, it shouldn't really be that difficult.

---

It appears that the source directory is in fact an NFS mount (we don't know what the destination directory is). This means that inotify can't be used.

The internet suggests that [FAM](http://oss.sgi.com/projects/fam/index.html) may be of use in this scenario.

Comment: The primary challenge is that the number of files in the source directory will reach 1 million soon, and traversing all files (with a simple script) to compare the source and target directory each and every time seems like a less than optimal approach.

Comment: Actually, the less than optimal approach was to put all the files in a single directory to start with. There are though utilities based upon incron that can monitor a directory and run commands when files are created/changed etc.

Comment: Yes it is. If all files are in a single directory Linux offers for instance [`inotify`](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki) to watch that directory for you, but changing the application that generates the filenames so a timestamp is included would already be a much better solution.

Comment: Yes, I meant `inotify` not `incron`.

Comment: The directory is an NFS share, and I believe I can't really use inotify for NFS shares.

Comment: That kind of information should have been provided in your question rather thay as an aside i a comment. That makes it very much harder. The internet suggests [FAM](http://oss.sgi.com/projects/fam/index.html)